# Non-separability of normed spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

I would like some hints to decide when a normed space is separable or not. I really understood the definition and the classic examples of separable spaces but when I go to show that a space is non-separable, just I get lost.

Now, I'm trying to show that:

> Let be $C([a,b])=\{f:[a,b]\to \Bbb{R} : f \text{ is limited}\}$, with $a<b$, and consider $C([a,b])$ with the metric
>   $$d(f,g)=\sup_{x\in [a,b]}|f(x)-g(x)|.$$
>   Show that $(C([a,b]),d)$ is non-separable.

I appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: The set of functions which are zero except at *one* point, where the value is 1, is too big and its elements are too far apart for the space to be separable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is to mimic Cantor.

Suppose there exists a countable dense subset, say $\{f_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$.

Consider the sequence $x_n:=b-\frac{b-a}{n}$. Define the function $g(x)$ as follows:

Define $g(x_n)=a_n$, where $a_n=0$ if $f_n(x_n)>2$ or $f_n(x_n) <-2$, $a_n=4$ if $-2 \leq f_n(x_n) \leq 2$, and $g(x)=0$ in every other $x$. $g$ is clearly bounded. Note now that $d(g,f_n) \geq 1$ for every $f_n$, which contracits density of $\{f_n\}$.

OBS: Calling that space $C([a,b])$ can be misleading, since it is sometimes used for the continuous functions on $[a,b]$, which is a separable space (polynomials being dense).

Comment: Hi @AloizioMacedo, thank you for the advice and the help!

Answer (score 0):

One of important theorems about separability of a normed space is:

Let  $X$ be normed topological vector space. If $X'$, the dual space of $X$,
be separable then $X$ is itself separable. You can use this for separability of normed spaces. It should be noted that the converse in not true.